# What would people think about two disappeared people?

Tags: plot-explanation, fantastic-beasts, fantastic-beasts-where-to-find-them

- Senator Henry Shaw is killed
- Mary Lou is killed
- MACUSA fears their secret world has been exposed, but Newt releases his Thunderbird to disperse a potion as rainfall over the city that erases all **New Yorkers**' recent memories, as MACUSA wizards repair the destruction.

What about the dead senator and Credence's mother? Did the rain make people forget about them? I'm sure the senator is also known in many other cities. Others would wonder where he has gone, because the rain erased only **New Yorkers**' recent memories.

[image]
 Henry Shaw is popular all over the America.
 [image]
<sub>(source: [ytimg.com](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_Ms_YZ07JR4/maxresdefault.jpg))</sub>

Comment: One thing we now know is that it didn't erase all of their memories, only the bad ones, because swooping evil's poison is different than say a memory charm! So the answer probably is not that these people aren't still considered dead, but rather their deaths might now be remembered as peaceful or accidental, depending on where the line is for a "bad" memory is and/or how one works death into that. Good Q though!!

Comment: @DarthLocke I got that question while I was thinking about the film I have just watched. As I couldn't get an answer here for a day, I asked Rowling about that on Twitter. But I have just registered, and I got problems with logging back, so I don't know the answer yet. Let's hope it will be good. As soon as I get unblocked, I'll post an answer with Rowling's official answer.

Comment: @DarthLocke I'm really sorry for my awful grammar. 

Comment: No worries, I'm American and I misspell my own language all the time and everyone else on here has been so nice (or taking advantage earning some points) to fix all of my mistakes. It's just a team effort to make everything look as good as possible. You're doing fine!!  :)